# Military expenditure over time

Tags: military, war, economy

The following graph from the [world bank website](http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/MS.MIL.XPND.GD.ZS?end=2015&start=1988&view=chart&year=2015) shows the world wide military expenditure in percentage of the world GDP over time from 1988 to 2015

[image]

I am trying to find similar data over a much longer period of time. Over the last 3000 years would be ideal! Of course, I realize that such data might result from very rough estimations and might eventually be specific to a certain area of the world and arguably not representative.

**Where could I find similar data over a much longer period of time?**

Comment: Interesting question! (I agree, 3000 may produce data of a *highly* speculative nature - not least in terms of global GDP). Also, that's an interesting spike just before 2010. I wonder what precipitated that? The gradual rise after 9/11 is also interesting.

Comment: You're not going to get 3000 years of good data.  You're probably not even going to get 100 years.  But data for the time period including World War II should be out there somewhere.

Comment: @ShimonbM Perhaps it was Obama's "surge" before withdrawal from Afghanistan: http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/8389778.stm.

Comment: This might be a good place to start: https://ourworldindata.org/military-spending/

Comment: @ShimonbM world GDP fell in 2009 due to the GFC. Since the graph is a ratio, when GDP falls the graph rises even if spending is flat. I don't know if spending was flat tho.

Comment: I do not have the graph, but I bet that it will show the same trend over the last 500 years. Military expenditures were a great share of total expenditures of pre-modern states.

Comment: Historical estimates of global GDP can be gotten from [Estimating World GDP, One Million B.C. - Present](http://holtz.org/Library/Social%20Science/Economics/Estimating%20World%20GDP%20by%20DeLong/Estimating%20World%20GDP.htm) by [J. Bradford DeLong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._Bradford_DeLong) an economic historian at UC Berkley. Global military spending comes from the [Stockholm International Peace Research Institute (SIPRI)](https://www.sipri.org/databases/milex) which is what the World Bank is using. While it has data back to 1950, its only complete back to 1988.

Comment: This would be a great question for a new SE forum called Militaria. https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/99463/militaria

Comment: @RichS Or the already-existing [Economics SE](https://economics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Spencer In response to your comment, I just flagged the post to ask for it to be migrated to economics.SE. We'll see if the moderators estimate this is a sound suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: I have asked the economics mods for feedback - looks like militaria has already been deleted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP requested migration to economics; economics agreed to migration, but the question is too old to migrate.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Thanks a lot for your help. I have now reposted the same question [here](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/25866/military-expenditure-over-time) on economics.SE.

Comment: Well done Remi.b